# Configuring JBoss AS 7.2 to log to syslog

Tags: syslog, jboss, rsyslog

In my `standalone.xml`, I have the `syslog-handler` configured like so:

```
<syslog-handler name="SYSLOG" enabled="true">
     <level name="INFO"/>
     <hostname value="i-XXXXXXX"/>
     <formatter><syslog-format syslog-type="RFC3164"/></formatter>
</syslog-handler>
...
<root-logger>
      <level name="INFO"/>
      <handlers>
          <handler name="SYSLOG"/>
          <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
          <handler name="FILE"/>
      </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

Yet, no output is delivered to `/var/log/syslog`. If I start jboss with `standalone.sh | logger`, I do see output there, so I presume my rsyslogd is set up / working reasonably (a stock Ubuntu install, FWIW).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I didn't have rsyslog's UDP listener turned on.  The `standalone.xml` configuration above is correct, I just had to add/uncomment this in `/etc/rsyslogd.conf`:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

/ht to jamezp in #wildfly on freenode for the help.

Comment: That jamezp dude sure is helpful! :)